# how to config Kong force HTTP to redirect to HTTPS

Tags: kong

As the kong doc https://getkong.org/docs/0.13.x/admin-api/#add-certificate , if we want our website to support https, we should do:

```
curl -i -X POST \
  --url http://localhost:8001/certificates \
  --data 'cert =-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----...'
  --data 'key =-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----..'
  --data 'snis =example.com'
```

Now, the website is supporting `https`, but it's also supporting `http`.
How we can force `http` to redirect to `https`.

ps: there is a plugin(https://getkong.org/plugins/dynamic-ssl). it has a option `config.only_https=true`. It seems to force to https. But, what's the difference between the `dynamic-ssl` plugin and the `/certificates` api.

Answer (score 2):

I know it's too late and probably you found your answer, this answer is for other people like me who faced the same issue:

When creating APIs in Kong, as said [here](https://docs.konghq.com/0.13.x/proxy/#restricting-the-client-protocol-http-https) you can force the protocol to be HTTPS, but it seems there is no way stated in references to **redirect** HTTP traffic to HTTPS, the only way I've found is to change Kong's nginx template and force-redirect all requests to https, which is not what I want though...
by the way, you can do this by creating a template very similar to what is discussed in [this link](https://getkong.org/docs/0.13.x/configuration/#custom-nginx-configuration) and adding the following configuration:

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;
        server_name _;
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }
```

then you should run your kong instance with `kong start --nginx-conf custom_nginx.template`

And then, Kong will use your server block rules in nginx.

Answer (score 1):

go to service that you want to redirect to https select on plugins -> Add Plugin -> Serverless -> Pre Function & paste value below to functions.

```
local scheme = kong.request.get_scheme()
if scheme == "http" then
  local host = kong.request.get_host()
  local query = kong.request.get_path_with_query()
  local url = "https://" .. host ..query
  kong.response.set_header("Location",url)
  return kong.response.exit(302,url)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Same deal than *M-N*. I'd like to give my solution as well :

You can use this Kong plugin : https://github.com/dsteinkopf/kong-http-to-https-redirect.
This is a fork because the original project is not compatible with Kong 1.x.

1) I cloned it to `/usr/local/share/lua/5.1/kong/plugins/http-to-https-redirect`.

2) I added this plugin in my Kong YAML configuration :

```yml
plugins:
  # ... my plugins
  name: http-to-https-redirect
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: plugin 'http-to-https-redirect' not enabled

Answer (score 0):

A bit late, you can use pre-function plugins to redirect to https

```
local scheme = kong.request.get_scheme()
if scheme == "http" then
local host = kong.request.get_host()
local query = kong.request.get_path_with_query()
local url = "https://" .. host ..query
kong.response.set_header("Location",url)
return kong.response.exit(302,url)
end
```

https://github.com/Kong/kong/issues/1946#issuecomment-485830359

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to override the complete NGINX template nor you need to use any plugin. You can write include directives and include the snippet in the HTTP block in Kong's config file.

First, write the HTTPS redirection rules. I placed this file at `/etc/kong/nginx-https.conf`:

```sh
server {
    listen      80;
    server_name api.mysite.com;
    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}
```

And then in my Kong config file at `/etc/kong/kong.conf`, I included the code snippet:

```sh
........
........
nginx_http_include = /etc/kong/nginx-https.conf
```

And I restarted the Kong service. More information regarding this can be found at the official website [here](https://docs.konghq.com/gateway-oss/2.4.x/configuration/#including-files-via-injected-nginx-directives).

Comment: This broke ACME

Answer (score 0):

using the deck config, it is quit easy, just change the

```
- https_redirect_status_code: 426
```

in to

```
- https_redirect_status_code: 301
```

and in the protocols in the route remove the http, and leave https:

```
protocols:
- https
```